# Hardhat deployment to mainnet

Tags: mainnet, hardhat-deploy

I am preparing for a smart contract deployment to mainnet and I plan on using hardhat.  I am trying to find out if there is a dry run style deployment that will simulate the deployment without actually deploying.  I would also like to get a better estimate of the gas to deploy my contract.  I have deployed to both ropsten and rinkeby fine and I use `hardhat-eth-gasreporter` but I want a stronger estimate of gas on mainnet and more assurance that the deployment will be successful.

Essentially I am nervous and looking for any tooling to help better prepare.